# Adding hyperlinks, descriptions and current date into an sqlite database?

Tags: python, sqlite

so I have a piece of code which I need it to run through a list called `vuln_list` and add each run of the loop into an SQLite database.

Here's the code:

```
def product_scan(product_name):

    # vulnerability links list
    vuln_list = []

    # counter for how many vulns per product
    count = 0
    for entry in d.entries:
        if product_name in entry.title:
            count += 1
            # here we append the hyperlinks, product names and today's date to a list so we can manipulate it later
            vuln_list.append(entry.link + entry.title)

    for entry in vuln_list:
        c.executemany('INSERT INTO nvd_table VALUES (?, ?, CURRENT_DATE)', vuln_list)
```

when I run this new bit of code I added (the last two lines) I get this error:

`sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 109 supplied.`. What I don't understand is what is this `109 supplied`. To my knowledge, I am only inserting the link and the title and today's date, which is 2 + today's date.

my SQLite table looks like this:

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE nvd_table (
                        hyperlink text,
                        product text,
                        date_added )''')
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `vuln_list` is only 1 dimensional and in the line `vuln_list.append(entry.link + entry.title)` you concat the two strings to one, ie. your vuln_list contains 109 entries (each containing a "linktitle").

So I would build a two dimensional list and then either skip your second for loop and use `c.executemany`. Or keep it but then use `c.execute('INSERT...', entry)`, NOTE: the argument should be entry and not the complete list, cause otherwise all records would be inserted 109 times.